# Debounce number of third party API calls my node server makes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, debouncing

**Requirements**

I have a node.js server using express that calls a third party API to get data when a user clicks reload on their frontend client.

I want to debounce the API calls my server makes to this third party API so I stay within their limits.

The third party API returns all of the data for all users, so when one user requests a reload, every users data will be reloaded.

Therefore, whenever a user clicks reload on their frontend client I only want to call the thirty party API if no other user has reloaded the API within the last 5 minutes.

**This is a C4 diagram showing how I want to control the API calls**[image: C4 Diagram showing desired flow]

**Problem**

I'm not sure how to implement this as I will need to track the number of third party API calls globally on my node.js server and not just in the instance when a user calls my API to request reloaded data.

If anyone has any advice, that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need a `debounce`.  Instead you can try `cache`.  `Debounce` is for  stopping a current request if there's a new incoming request; whereas, you want the respond with the same `cached payload` if requests are made in a span of 5 minute intervals.  Right?